# How to make Arduino IDE upload Files automaticaly?

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to find out how to automatically upload my HTML files with the Arduino IDE.
Somehow I always get this error:

```
Warning: Problem accessing board folder /www/sd.
```

Comment: You forgot to mention for which Arduino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I investigated in this once.

Sadly Arduino does not write good enough docs for each board.
But here is a solution that should work for all openWRT and Linino based boards:

1. SSH in to your board. See [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/LinuxCLI) if you don't know how.
2. Then type: `#vi /etc/config/uhttpd`
3. Look for this section:

   ```
   # Server document root
   option home /somepath/xyz
   ```
4. Create `/mnt/sda1/arduino/www/sd` by using: `mkdir -p /mnt/sda1/arduino/www/sd`
5. Create a symlink: `ln -sf /mnt/sda1/arduino/www/ /somepath/xyz/mypath`
   replace `/somepath/xyz` with the path found in the config file of point 2.
6. Test it with a file: `#echo Hello World! >/mnt/sda1/arduino/www/test.txt`
7. Open browser and type the adress of your board like: 
   `www.[arduinoName].local/mypath/test.txt`
8. You should now see the text: "Hello World!"

you have now created a simlink to your specific URL on the webserver of the Arduino. To enable automatic upload of Files you have to add one more specific symlink:

9. `ln -sf /mnt/sda1/arduino/www/sd /www/sd`

This symlink creates a direct upload path of all your files that you stored on your computer in the www folder beside your sketch.

```
ArduinoProject
|-- ArduinoProject.ino
+-- www
    |-- index.html
```